# maven: how to include a local file at a specific file path point in the target

Tags: xml, maven

I need to replace a file that is automatically downloaded by Maven with a local one that I've configured.  Any insight on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: which file? downloaded where? at what time? how is xml related?

Comment: @eis It's an xml file that is part of a library that is downloaded automatically via my pom file and maven.  I simply need my own personally configured version of this xml file to be included in the target instead of the "stock" one that maven tries to pull with the library.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your constraints, but as far as I understand your context you may need to 'patch' the artifact and release it with your own group ID (if the license allows that). Than reference your artifact as a dependency.

You may need to exclude the old artifact if it is a transitive dependency. Here is [more information on dependency management and exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Comment: everyone seems to be overthinking this.  So what I need is to take a working war file and inject a file into it.  That's it.  Except, when I scp my working war file back to my local box and explode it, even if I re-jar it with the exact same name tomcat still won't work...this is my dilemma...

Comment: And this happens even when I make NO CHANGES to the war file itself.  I literally scp it back to make box, explode it, make no changes, put it back to a war using jar command, scp it back to the remote box and restart tomcat and tomcat can't find stuff blah blah blah...

Comment: So it seems that this is a jar-on-your-development-box and tomcat problem? Nothing to do with Maven (as the title of your question suggests ;) )? Maybe the error message could give a clue?

Comment: "everyone seems to be overthinking this"... probably because you're not really providing meaningful information. You've tagged it with maven and xml, but it doesn't seem to be related to either maven or xml. If the problem is with packaging a war file, it would help if you'd provide the exact steps you're doing now.